# NVIDIA Drivers cause WMI corruption

Tags: wmi, nvidia

Several versions of recent NVIDIA drivers are corrupting WMI. We discovered this when our systems stopped being able to update group policy, run resultant set of policy, and other items were broken. This affects both Windows 10 and Windows 11 - I've only tested on 64-bit versions.

What happens is, when the driver installs, it wipes out the following registry key:
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Wbem\CIMOM\Autorecover MOFs`

You'll see an almost empty list, and the first entry will be something like this:
`C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERSTORE\FILEREPOSITORY\NVDM.INF_AMD64_63A490995FFE8D23\NVWMI\NVWMI.MOF`

Note, usually the first line in this key is blank, so it may look empty under normal conditions. You need to open it to see the contents.

By itself, this key does not break anything. However, this key is leveraged when the operating system detects and attempts to repair issues in WMI. An example that would trigger the issue would be when manually running `winmgmt /resetrepository`. When this happens, Windows references the above registry key to determine what WMI providers to rebuild. Because the key is wiped out, losing all of the out of box providers, WMI will essentially be hosed breaking numerous things on the system.

The versions of problematic drivers are currently being offered by Microsoft (through Windows Update), Dell, and other manufacturers. In other words, if you simply allow windows to update itself or try to update the driver from the manufacturer it will corrupt this registry key. The problematic driver is `nvdm.inf` which tries to add a WMI provider during installation. Likely the installation is trying to prune any old entries of NVIDIA providers, and instead wipes the key out completely.

However, I have confirmed that the latest NVIDIA driver currently offered (Version 537.99) does NOT cause this issue. It is also clearly architected differently and there isn't even an nvdm.inf file anymore.

I've thoroughly eliminated any other possibilities, and this problem occurs soon after reinstalling Windows fresh, and allowing it to install the NVIDIA driver from Microsoft. It also occurs whenever the affected versions of drivers are installed, regardless of source. I've confirmed the following NVIDIA display driver versions cause the problem:

- From Dell: 31.0.15.2892
- From Microsoft: 31.0.15.2852

Version 31.0.15.3799 in the latest package straight from NVIDIA (537.99) does not cause this issue.

I've found [one other reference to this same type of bug with an HP package](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c04726890). Unfortunately, their recommendation and what I have discovered is that the "fix" is to copy the key from a similar system. However, if WMI has already been corrupted it can be difficult if not impossible to get everything working correctly again. We've found that restoring the key and rebuilding WMI still does not repair all the issues, and this doesn't account for any 3rd party providers that were installed before the driver installation.

This is quite the nasty bug and has likely set up a ticking time bomb on hundreds of thousands of computers. It has effected hundreds of computers in our organization which are predominantly Dell laptops with NVIDIA graphics cards.

I'm not sure how this might help anyone, but it's best to catch this proactively and restore the key before WMI gets hosed, while simultaneously making sure the latest NVIDIA driver is installed before trying to use any Microsoft or manufacturer provided drivers.

Comment: If you have that many Dell laptops then perhaps you have a Dell rep who can get the issue escalated.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Even if I did, this would address the issue only for Dell and what a nightmare that would be trying to convince anybody over there to do anything. NVIDIA appears to have identified, and silently fixed the issue. Now we're waiting for everyone else to play catch up... Just imagine how many places this drivers has been embedded amongst vendors.

Comment: On my Windows 11 with NVIDIA "Autorecover MOFs" is empty, but I don't have any problem with WMI (such as described [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-repair-or-rebuild-the-wmi-repository-on-windows-10)).

Comment: (For anyone who doesn't want to accept all the cookies in the link given by harrymc, you can use the [Google cache version](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tKa3OuyZ_BgJ:https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-repair-or-rebuild-the-wmi-repository-on-windows-10&hl=en&gl=uk).)

Comment: @harrymc as the article states, the key should not be empty. If it is, they say copy it from a known good source the run `winmgmt /resetrepository` again. You don't have a problem because your system has not attempted to repair WMI. When and if it does, or you do manually, it will be corrupt.

Comment: It can look empty if the first line is a blank line :p

Comment: @Appleoddity If you tell you tell your Dell rep and they spread the information within Dell then at least there is some chance that affected Dell users can get a faster answer that they're, umm, up "the wrong" creek without a paddle, and Dell can tell Microsoft and Nvidia that they need to do better *now*.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, the first line is usually a blank line. So, yes, you need to open the key and look at it. Thanks.

Comment: I confirm - I have *lots* of entries inside the key, and the entry only looks empty because of the blank line.

Comment: @harrymc Further to that, with a *minimal* search, I couldn't find any requirement for a registry entry of type REG_MULTI_SZ to start with an empty (zero-terminated) string. But I don't think that's important.

Comment: @Appleoddity Can you add an example of the relevant section of "nvdm.inf" to the question, please? (Is that the correct filename? I have Nvidia drivers installed, and even [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) does not find any file with that name.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton: This line might be caused by the driver bug.